# I have question / issue with connection to IBKR

Tags: connection, trading, interactive-brokers, broker

i couldn't connect to IBKR through TradingView. i already have demo and real account in IBKR, but the system doesn't give me permission to connect. even new windiw didn't open. 2-3 minutes loading and error. why such type of issue apperead?

i bought subscription Plus. but the issue didn't fixed.

Comment: I think the only ways to connect with IBKR are with Trader WorkStation (TWS) and the IB Gateway.